# Unset variable names stored in another variable gives error

Tags: zsh

Why does the following

```
MY_VARS="VAR1 VAR2 VAR3"
unset "$MY_VARS"
```

give me an error?

```
unset: VAR1 VAR2 VAR3: invalid parameter name
```

Comment: Sorry it seems to be specific to `zsh`.  Retagged and fixed typo

Comment: Without doublequotes, yes, it works fine here. `MY_VARS=(VAR1 VAR2 VAR3); unset "${MY_VARS[@]}"` also works.

Comment: Oh, okay. Deleted the comment as it's irrelevant now.

Comment: Using an array works for `zsh`.  Wonder why the discrepancy.  If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.  Better yet if you know why this happens :D

Comment: Apparently zsh doesn't perform word splitting on strings resulting from variable expansions by default. `unset ${=MY_VARS}` works, the equals sign preceding the variable name forces word splitting. I don't know much about zsh so I don't think I would be able to post a good answer to this. Thanks though

Comment: Arrays exist primarily to support lists of arguments. Your attempt isn't trying to unset three variables; it's trying to unset a *single* variable named `VAR1 VAR2 VAR3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Use an array. `MY_VARS=(VAR1 VAR2 VAR3); unset "${MY_VARS[@]}"`

---

You are trying to unset a single variable named `VAR1 VAR2 VAR3`, not three variables named `VAR1`, `VAR2`, and `VAR3`.

If `zsh` performed word-splitting on unquoted parameter expansions by default, you could write

```
unset $MY_VARS
```

but it does not. You can enable that explicitly with

```
setopt SH_WORD_SPLIT
unset $MY_VARS
```

or enable it just for this one expansion (as indicated by oguz ismail in a comment)

```
unset ${=MY_VARS}
```

However, the "right" way to do this is to use an array.

```
MY_VARS=(VAR1 VAR2 VAR3)
unset "${MY_VARS[@]}"
```